# How to format logfile in YYYYMMDD format?

Tags: java

I need to get the date in the following format: YYYYMMDD

Have code which outputs below result.

[2023-02-13 11:05:03] [SEVERE ] sever message

System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format",
"[%1$tF %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n");

But I wanted to be like this [20230213 11:05:03] [SEVERE ] sever message

Comment: Which logging framework are you using?

Comment: Logger  private static Logger LOGGER = null;

    static {
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format",
                "[%1$tF %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n");
        LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FileProcessing.class.getName());
    }

Comment: Read [`SimpleFormatter.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)) and [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) The format `%1$tF` simply means _"ISO 8601 complete date formatted as "%tY-%tm-%td". "_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the format of the date to YYYYMMDD, you need to modify the value of the `"java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format"` property.

Try changing it to the following:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format",  [%1$tY%1$tm%1$td %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n");
```

In this format, `%1$tY` will give you the 4-digit year, `%1$tm` will give you the 2-digit month, and `%1$td` will give you the 2-digit day. This way, the date will be displayed in the desired format.